# Converting strings to time

Tags: python-3.x, string, datetime

I have strings that I need to convert to times.
Examples are:

- `str1 = '23:11'`
- `str2 = '2:23'`
- `str3 = '1:12:13'`

I can easily convert the first string using:

```
print(cleant,(datetime.strptime(cleant,"%M%S")).strftime("%M:%S"))
```

If I try to do the same for str2 and 3 then the first 2 digits are taken as the minutes or hours respectively and a 0 is added to the beginning of the seconds and the results are shown as:

- 22:03
- 11:21:03

How can I have it so the 0 would be added to the first section of the time? If there is no hour but less than 10 minutes then the 0 is added there if the hour exists but is less than 10 the 0 is added there.
Maybe there is a format that I'm missing that `datetime` already has.

Comment: Sounds like splitting by `:` and building a datetime from the pieces would be easier than fiddling around with different formats for `strptime`

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand how your examples and the "results" are related. What is your input, what is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed `:` in `strptime`.
Try to use

```
try:
    # this handles 23:11 and 2:23
    datetime.strptime(cleant,"%M:%S")
except ValueError:
    # this handles 1:12:13
    datetime.strptime(cleant,"%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: I added the .time() to the end as I only needed the time portion. This worked perfectly for what I need.
Thanks again